# not opening showing whole next interface when running this"npm run dev"

Tags: next.js

[[image of command which is run in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwZcO.png)][image of interface showing after running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q16bp.png)]

I am trying to run the next app , but it is showing the only white screen on the browser and also stuck at the terminal when compiling it